# Android Facebook login pop-up dialog

Tags: java, android, facebook

My Android App is published on Google Store. I am integrating Facebook login in my App.Everything run perfect on my device and different devices. However Facebook disabled my Facebook app for reason of violating 8.1 login.

I am not able to replicate issue that happing with Facebook testers.
Moreover I am seeing different dialog of Facebook login as attached than I am having in my devices.

Would you let me know what device or OS version that show attached dialog.

Thanks
Facebook Testing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v47fg.png)

My Devices
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJGND.png)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook testing image shows the dialog that comes up to users who have Facebook app installed and they are logged in. Your image shows the dialog that comes up to users who don't have Facebook app installed, so they are presented with web page option to log in.